# EditWorkManager method getWorkInfoByIdLiveData not giving the WorkInfo

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I'm trying to get my WorkerInfo with the getWorkInfoByLiveData method that exists in the WorkManager instance.

```
val workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uuid).value
```

The WorkInfo is always null. Also, I'm calling this method from the main thread.

The scenario of how I'm checking this method. I try to enqueue my worker when a user sends a network request and if the internet is not connected I simply register a work with the WorkManager. After some time if I try to get the WorkerInfo with the **UUID**, it'll always give me null.

**Note:** When calling **getWorkInfoByLiveData** the Worker is not executed at that time.

Don't I'm expecting from WorkManager to give me WorkInfo with **ENQUEUED** State.

**Edit 1:**
So, another scenario would be like this, the app on which I'm working is like a social app. Now after registering a first worker, let's say the user don't want to see the posts from a specific user so this where I need to register my second worker because the user internet is not available at this time. Now what I need to do is to cancel the previously registered worker and then create a Chain of workers with not to show post of a user to **beginWith** and **then** the fetch all posts. Now in order to cancel the worker, I check that if the previous worker is still in Enqueued State then cancel it and create a new chain or workers.

Here is the code.

```
fun Context.isWorkerRegistered(uuid: UUID?): Boolean {
   val id = uuid ?: return false
   val workerInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(id).value
   return workerInfo?.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED
}
```

The **workInfo** instance is always null.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**:  Livedata won't calculate the value until an active observer is added.

`getWorkInfoByIdLiveData()` returns a `LiveData<WorkInfo>` that you need to observe to get the workInfo value:

```
val status = workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uuid)
                        .observe(this, Observer{ workInfo ->

    if (workInfo!=null){
        // ...
    }
}
```

you can take a look at the [WorkManager's codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/index.html) to see how it can be used.

Comment: Yes, I know that but the getValue method always returns the current value according to LiveData documentation. So, don't you think when I enqueue the worker on WorManager and after that, it needs to give me WorkInfo with the **UUID**.

Comment: LiveData is to watch the data and distribute it to the observers. It won't calculate the value until an active observer is added.

Comment: This article can be useful to understand this topic: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04

Comment: Now if you see in the [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04) the unit test for this data  `assertEquals(viewModel.liveData1.value, "foo") // Passes`  is passed even if there are no active observers. Well that's because the getValue always give you the last value.
Also, for my case, I have one active observer too but still not getting the value

Comment: Can you then post some more of the code that you have in your app? when/where are you observing this livedata?

Comment: Updated the question